# How to know which type of Html object is using jQuery click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I know on which type of HTML object I have clicked using jQuery?

For Example, If I click on Button then it should inform me that This is button object or Text input or Textarea... like that.

Why I asked this question?

Because I am facing one issue of this type.

I have one Textarea and just below underneath I have file input HTML object. I have bound Caret function (which returns current cursor position in Textarea) to that Textarea. But when I click on Browse button to upload file it gives me an error. So I want to prevent this by know which type of HTML object is?

Comment: It sounds to me like you should be using different event handlers for different object types if you intend to offer different behavior for the different clicks.

Comment: @jfriend00, Actually I support Inline Editing in Web App using XML. When User click on an element and then I dynamically create Textarea and just below if "file" input. Now when I click on file input, a JavaScript error occurs from a function which is bound to Textarea :(

Comment: Something is wrong if events from a button area going to a textarea right next to it.  That is not supposed to happen.  If events are bubbling up the hierarchy and that's the issue you're trying to deal with, then that is another matter and there could be several different approaches to solve it, but we'd have to understand more of the HTML structure and see the relevant code to know what to recommend.  One big chunk of code that branches based on object type is usually not the best way to set things up (not very object oriented or encapsulated).

Comment: By tracing I found that `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is doing issue. When I comment inclusion of jQuery then file input works but when I uncomment it then it stops. You can view [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064304/jquery-jquery-1-7-1-min-js-issue-with-file-input-in-google-chrome-29-0-1547-76-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may do it like

```
$(".myBtn").click(function(){

       alert($(this).prop("tagName"));

});
```

#### update

here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fMDb/1/)

Comment: If I want to return `tagName` from this click event and want to store it in javascript variable and want to access return value from that variable then How can I do it?

Comment: like `var typeOfInput = jQuery(id).click(function(){
  return (jQuery(this).prop("tagName"));
 });`

Comment: @user2825534 : the handler function for click is a callback. you should not return any values from it. instead you may want to put the logic that depends on the return value(`tagname`) inside the callback function itself.

Answer (score 1):

in the click event

```
function(e){
    var type=$(this).prop('tagName'); // I think it will need jQuery >1.6
    // or
    var type=$(this)[0].tagName;
}
```

Actually, there are quite a few posts in the past about this question.

Comment: the second case would have to be `this.tagName` or `$(this)[0].tagName` as it is an attribute of the DOM element not the jQuery object

Comment: Thank you DGS. It is not the first time I forgot it.

Comment: what if element is `<input type="button">`? In your case it will return `input`.I think user want 'button' op

Comment: `this.type` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well you may use attr("tagName") which will return name of the tag.

Example code snippet: Suppose you click on some element having id as #myId then bind click event and get the attr("tagName") (The jQuery way)

```
$('#myId').on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('tagName'));
});
```

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NQfZh/7/)

```
$(this).attr("tagName")
```

or can use

```
 $(this).prop('tagName');
```

reference **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** and **[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="log"></div>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Button">
<input type="submit" id="myButton" value="submit">
<input type="text" id="myButton" value="text">
<input type="date" id="myButton" value="date">
<textarea>Test</textarea>
<script>
$("input, textarea").on('click', function (e) {
    $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName + " Type: " + this.type);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I want to return tagName from this click event and want to store it in javascript variable and want to access return value from that variable then How can I do it?

Comment: like `var typeOfInput = jQuery(id).click(function(){ return (jQuery(this).prop("tagName")); });`

Comment: `var inputtype;
inputtype['type'] = this.type;
inputtype['name'] = event.target.nodeName;`

Answer (score 0):

$(e.target) - Contains DOM element user clicked on. We can use this object to get anything and everything regarding object user has clicked on.

e.target is always going to be the top element clicked.So while every click on the screen is technically click on the body, e.target will always return the furthest child element in the tree that occupies clicked area. However, we might have multiple absolutely positioned elements occupying the same area. In this case, the element with higher z-index will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some DOM properties to getting the object type:

```
e.target.nodeName
```

OR

```
e.target.tagName
```

For example:

HTML -

```
<input class="Track" type="button" value="Submit" />
 <button class="Track">Submit</button>
```

Jquery -

```
$('.Track').click(function (e) {
   alert("Object: " + e.target.nodeName + " Type: " + e.target.type);            
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/8fMDb/2/)